# Dropping an elbow

Tags: meaning

What does "dropping an elbow" mean?

Here is the context from the blog post ("[10 Ways to Be Closer to Your Siblings](https://www.realsimple.com/magazine-more/inside-magazine/life-lessons/close-siblings)," number 7 in that list) that I was reading:

> Remember, though, that there are different depths to each bond and that somewhere inside that group hug, someone is usually dropping an elbow.

Answer (score 1):

A technique employed in wrestling:

**Wikipedia:**

> A move in which a wrestler jumps or falls down on an opponent driving
>   his/her elbow into anywhere on the opponent's body. A common elbow
>   drop sees a wrestler raise one elbow before falling to one side and
>   striking it across an opponent.

Comment: Please cite your source.

Answer (score 0):

In this context it probably refers to the [wrestling technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professional_wrestling_attacks#Elbow_drop) of hitting the opponent downwards with one's elbow.